# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope, closed-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26397893/640731) is the question. I must admit that I can see 2 problems in this question.

1. A professional C++ programmer might say it is a beginner question.
   But AFAIK, beginner level questions can be asked in stackoverflow as
   long as it is well written and is not an obvious duplicate.
2. I don't think the OP is a native English speaker. But at least he
   explained in the question that what he is trying to accomplish with
   the code, and what result he is getting.

The question was closed with off topic reason

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
>   must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example."

But I do think it was unfair to close it because the question doesn't satisfy any of the close reasons.

> *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior*

OP clearly said what he is trying to accomplish.

> *a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*

OP said he is getting a wrong output of 1. The code he posted is not too long and can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Why do you care that the question is closed? It's not exactly a good question in the first place...

Comment: @l4mpi Probably because of these 1) If you just edit the language for OP, this question has enough material for others to answer 2) This is clearly not a give me codez kind of question. 3) I was a newbie once and [my first SO question before edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5338608/revisions) was worse than this and thankfully I didn't run away.

Comment: @l4mpi The better question is why *don't* you? You participate on meta, so therefore you obviously care about the quality of the site and that it remains a good resource for everyone (new users included). Everyone has to go through the learning stage, and with edits, it's become a pretty okay question. I'm not saying 100+, or even 10+, but it could actually help someone learn something, which is the only reason that this damn network exists.

Comment: @Yann4 I care about people who ask good questions and most importantly who do enough research. This IMO includes getting to a basic level of proficiency with a programming language _before_ starting to ask questions on SO; especially in case of debugging questions. New users should start by _lurking more_ and _reading_ a ton of stuff before ever asking their first question. The specific question is not total crap, but certailnly not _good_ either. And it takes away time and eyeballs from the _hard_ questions that currently require bounties to even receive enough attention in most tags.

Comment: @l4mpi Fair enough, although I think that that's assuming that everyone who is answering that sort of question *can* answer the hard questions. I know how to answer that sort of question, but I couldn't even begin with a lot of the bountied stuff, so I don't think the "takes time away" holds water.

Comment: @l4mpi, based on my experience, all basic question will get more response, complicated questions (spend more time and with more knowledge on the subject before asking) tends to get less response (too hard for anyone maybe? :)), and [even can get closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814501/misplaced-datagrid-error-indicator) (I don't know the answer for your question, and probably no one knows, so lets close it...)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the answer from [@user3427079](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274559/109702). It is a programming question, there's a code sample there. You even solve the OP's issue explaining why the execution path isn't what he thinks it is - how is this not programming? Incidentally I think your explanation of what the fault is the ideal way to answer that novice user's question - it's a better way to answer than just a *"use xyz instead"* because you explain how the current logic is faulty.

It doesn't matter whether it's homework or not - the question just has to be on topic and decently written.

Admittedly it's not a high quality question in its current state, and we don't want Stack Overflow to be a crowd sourced debugging resource. Nor do I want to tell the c++ regulars how to run their space. But remember, we were all novices at one stage. The appropriate thing to do with this question is for someone to be nice and take a couple of minutes to make it better - rephrase it so that this non-native English speaker understands what is required.

One minute we get lots of complaints that we're not kind enough to the n00bs, we're too scary and elitist. Then a newbie posts a question like that and it gets closed. Where's the community spirit?

Comment: Within 5 minutes of OP posting that question there was 2 close votes and 2 down votes. That is when I added the first comment about close votes.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I agree that this is also not a "we'll teach you how to use a debugger" site as well (as inferred by one of the comments), but if someone simply gave the answer that user3427079 did in his last paragraph, that could make a world of difference to this guy.

Comment: Exactly, but how can someone give that answer if the question is closed on site? It is easy to scare away people from site. Very easy

Comment: "One minute we get lots of complaints that we're not kind enough to the n00bs, we're too scary and elitist." - many people disagree with the sentiment that this is a bad thing. Similarily, @Krishnabhadra, IMO scaring people away is good, but happens too late - I'd like to scare away the people asking the hundreds of "Why I has NullPointerException" questions _before_ they ask! Also, I think the comment from GreenAsJade on the question hits the nail on the head: OP needs to learn debugging, not have other people debug his code for him - and teaching people debugging is too broad for SO.